# Cannot send email to removed Exchange 2010 contact

Tags: email, exchange-2010, contacts

I had setup an external contact in exchange (Mail Contact) for a contractor (let's say Joe User, forwarding to juser@hiscompany.com).

I was having the problem whereby any mail sent to Joe User from within exchange was always arriving at Joe's end with a winmail.dat attachment.  Figuring this may be related to the fact that I had Joe setup as a mail contact in exchange, I removed the contact from exchange.

Now from Outlook, if I compose an email to juser@hiscompany.com (as I would to any person not @mycompany.com) I get a delivery error, immediately, from exchange advising that the recipient 'Joe User@mycompany.com' can't be found.  It's as if Exchange is trying to resolve this locally, rather than delivering it externally.

Any suggestions on how to get Exchange to 'forget I ever added this guy as a mail contact' and deliver the mail externally as it would with any other domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your [nickname cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287623) in Outlook to deal with the delivery error.

You also might want to read these:

- [How to Prevent the Winmail.dat File from Being Sent to Internet Users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053)
- [Winmail.dat attachments are included in received e-mail messages in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278061)
- [How e-mail message formats affect Internet e-mail messages in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290809)

Comment: Exactly. Outlook is vigilant about this kind of thing, which is why us Exchange admins have to be real careful about changing peoples names after things like marriages. Do it wrong and everyone they ever emailed will start getting this exact error.